# How to flag a question about Certification Exams? (and where to ask them)

Tags: discussion, flags

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437429/how-to-prepare-for-test-c9550-412-ibm-business-process-management-express-or-st) is about a Certification Exam (of a "software tool") rather than the tool itself. How is the best way to flag it? If I choose the "off-topic" option, in my opinion, none of the alternatives seems to fit the scenario (#3 seems to be the closest one).

In addition, where would it be the best place to ask this kind of questions?

[image: Off-Topic]

Comment: I would tend to flag this with a custom close reason saying it's not really a programming question so it doesn't fit with Stack Overflow. Here is a meta discussion about asking certification questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268837/where-should-i-ask-a-question-about-certifications

Comment: FOr this question, I would go with Too broad or opinion based because tips for 1 person may be something normal for the other